# New images do not show up within the game

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, xna, render

Sorry if this question is a really basic one. I have really little knowledge of c# or visual studios.

I have been tasked with making simple modifications to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254916%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) small c# platformer game for windows desktop. To start with I have changed the render of the main character, enemy and pick-up item. But I don't see these changes within the game when I run it! I have completely removed the original renders from the games Sprites folder, restarted C# and restarted my computer but when I run the game in debug mode within Visual Studios 2010 the original renders remain. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: How could we possibly know this without seeing the corresponding code? Have you built the project?

Comment: @antonijn No it was assigned by my college tutor. I wondered if there was a standard way Visual studios handles project assets that would mean originals stay intact after their corresponding images files are replaced!?

Comment: When you say "run the game" are you rebuilding the project and running it, or simply running the exe again without building?

Comment: @Steven I am clicking the green triangle. When I hover over it it says "start debugging (F5)".

Comment: Just noticed I have an error "The referenced component Content could not be found." Could this be related?

Comment: yes it is, read my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably look for the resources being saved in your project. They are kept in a collection that is attached to your project file. you can find it in the Project settings:

[How to Add/Remove project resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4.aspx)

This would be the first thing I would check as removing the file does not remove it from the project (and if these resources are compiled intot he project that explains why they have not disappeared yet.)

You need to replace the reference to this resource with your new ones. Remove the old images from the project resources and add the new ones under the same name so you can avoid refactoring your code. Clean your project, rebuild your project as @Steven Mills mentions, then let us know if it worked.

**Edit:**
Extra reading:

- [Linked and Embedded Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht9h2dk8.aspx)
- [Now with pictures!](http://fczaja.blogspot.se/2010/11/visual-studio-adding-and-using-resource.html)

Comment: I looked at the links you shared. When I right click my project and go to properties there is no "resources" in the menu of options. I dont know if this is related but I have a "references" folder in my solution explorer which have Mircrosoft.Xna.Framework and another folder called Content References.

Comment: Heres a picture of what it currently looks like: www.chrismepham.com/pics/game.png

Comment: @crm Right you have at some point deleted the content reference from this project. Is "Content References" or anything similar to this included in your Reference Paths or Content Build tabs in the  Platformer window (the same one you show in your picture?)

Comment: Thanks for pursuing this. This is the link for the platformer game prodivded by msdn: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Platformer-68643e63 Perhaps you could doanlod and see it for yourself, its only 7.8MB. Id really appreciate your help.

Comment: You won't learn if you make me do it ;) Try to reimport the references you need or start from scratch with the project in that link and add your content on top of it (making sure not to remove the references)

Comment: that's the bizarre thing. I haven't made any changes to the project, that's how it comes once downloaded and opened.